# Google Plus JS API AddActivity

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus

I'm trying to use Google's JS API to post on the currently logged in user's stream / wall / whatever. I've gotten to a point where everything seems like it should be working (No errors in my chrome js console) but nothing shows up on my google+ page. 
My code looks like this:

```
<html>  
    <head>
    <title>Google+ API Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleAPIOnLoad() {
            console.log("Google plus js loaded... calling client.load...");
            gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(e){
                console.log("client loaded...");
                console.log(e);
            });
        }

        function signIn() {
            console.log("signing in...");
            gapi.auth.authorize({
                client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
                immediate: false,
                response_type: "token",
                scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"],
                request_visible_actions: "https://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
            }, function(e) {
                // callback
                console.log("done!", e);

                gapi.client.request({
                    path: "plus/v1/people/me/moments/vault",
                    method: "POST",
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        type: "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
                        target: {
                            id: "SOME_UNIQUE_ID_12345",
                            type: "http://schema.org/Thing",
                            name: "This is a test",
                            description: "Hi there, this is a test",
                            image: "http://mentationaway.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/fractal.jpg"
                        }
                    })
                }).execute(function(e) {
                    console.log("did it.", e);
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=googleAPIOnLoad"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Sign In" onclick="signIn()">
</body>
</html>`
```

I removed my client_id obviously. I've been looking at this page ( http://wheresgus.com/appactivitiesdemo/ ), which claims that it can make an activity, but even when I test with that, I still don't see anything on my google+ page. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App activities appear in a special place on Google+ specific to each app. To see all of your app activities, go to:

https://plus.google.com/apps/activities

To see app activities by app, visit here:

http://plus.google.com/apps

And select the app you want to see activities for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm dumb... I should have known what an activity is. My original goal was to post to the stream. Is that possible to do with the JS api?

Comment: In an effort to ensure that the Google+ stream is not spammy, you cannot programmatically post directly to the stream. The right way to share to your stream is with a Google+ share [https://developers.google.com/+/web/share] or Interactive post (preferred) [https://developers.google.com/+/features/interactive-posts]

Comment: Thanks! I found the info I was looking for here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive